# Entity framework change table name programmatically

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to change a tablename programmatically in the entity framework?
I got 2 runtime parameters determine a table. All tables have the same structure, the only difference is the name. I know I can add the two paramaters as columns, but different tables are beter in this case.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you need to be able to change it on the fly, or before EF is initialized for the first time? I don't believe the former option is possible, but the second one could be.

Comment: We need it on the fly. The end user fills the parameters. Problem is that the table will become too big if we add 2 columns for the parameters. Parameters make a logical split.

Comment: For those who looking for solution there is a nice one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51899590/4745982

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Code First (or reverse-engineering a Code First context for an existing database) you can use the `Table` attribute:

```
[Table("tablename")
public class MyEntity
{
    //stuff
}
```

This will change the name of the table to whatever you put in the string.

Alternatively, you can use the Fluent Configuration API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
      .ToTable("tablename");
}
```

Comment: I know, but the parameters are filled in runtime.