# Entity Framework map model class to table at run time

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In a project using ASP.NET Core 2.0 and Entity Framework, I'm trying to map a known table schema (coded into class `MyTableClass`) to an unknown table name. This table name is given by the user at run time, so this is done outside of the `OnModelCreating` method of the Context class. Is there a way to do something like the following pseudocode:

```
void OnUserEnteredTableNameFromUI(string tableName)
{
    var modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder(???);  // how?
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyTableClass>().ToTable(tableName);
    // how to get a ref to DbSet<MyTableClass> myTable from here?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen situations where databases with identical structure but varying table names had been deployed to several sites. In that case, EF only needs the know the table name(s) at application startup.

This can be done by adding a constructor parameter to the context:

```cs
private readonly string _userDefinedTableName;

public MyContext(string userDefinedTableName)
{
    _userDefinedTableName = userDefinedTableName;
}
```

Then, in `OnModelCreating`:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTableClass>().ToTable(_userDefinedTableName);
```

However, in your case the name has to change any number of times at runtime. With Entity Framework, that's impossible (well, more exactly, too impractical to really contemplate it). EF compiles and stores model once per context class, because it would be too expensive to do all that for each context instantiation.

That means that `OnModelCreating` runs not more than once in an application and the first table name remains.

You'll have to find other ways to address table data dynamically, or change the design so the multiple tables can be converted into one fixed table.

Comment: The thing is more complicated though because `OnModelCreating` by default is called only once per context type (and options?)

Comment: I think that should do, at least, I took it that this table name should be specified only once, i.e. depending on the connected database.

Comment: I wanted to use EF to work with similar tables in the db, table name is dependent on some value entered by a user, and is changeable. So your approach doesn't work for the reason that Ivan stated. I assume this is not possible for now and I'm changing the design to have a single table instead. It was probably a bad design in the first place anyway.

Comment: OK, so the name has to change several times during the life-time of one application. That's indeed not easy with EF because EF initializes (and stores) the compiled model only once. You *could* initialize and store compiled models manually for each table name, but that should be a last resort if everything else fails and the requirement can't be dropped. Fortunately, in your case there's a better alternative.

Comment: I think it can be valuable for future readers to see why you wanted this initially (explain in the question) and how you solved this. I've seen people struggling with similar issues before. I'll remove my answer but I'd love to see the result of our discussion preserved somehow.

Comment: I have an unusual scenario where I allow user to upload a dataset of arbitrary schema, the back-end store that dataset in a new dynamically created table using ADO. Now I have a common way to process the dataset and store the outputs to a new table (`MyTableClass`). Initially I wanted these results table to be separated from each other. But I guess I should create a key pair of (`datasetId`, `datarowId`) in `MyTableClass` and store all the results together.

Comment: if the answer is "No, you can't do it with EF", then I'll accept your answer if you could add it. I think it's a valuable discussion to keep.

Comment: OK, I modified the answer.

Comment: @Gert, this can be made working by implementing custom `IModelCacheKeyFactory`. It's the service interface controlling the model caching.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is an interesting issue which might help other people that need some dynamic model building, here is how it can be implemented.

Let say we have a custom context with custom table name provided via constructor (as Gert Arnold suggested in the other answer):

```cs
public class CustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    // …

    private string customTableName;
    public string CustomTableName => customTableName ?? "DefaultCustomTableName";
}
```

and we use it inside the `OnModelCreating` (it should be there, currently there is no other simple way to create model using the predefined convention sets):

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomEntity>().ToTable(CustomTableName);
```

The only problem is that by default the `OnModelCreating` is called just once per context type and is cached. Luckily EF Core is built on top of a (replaceable) services architecture. The service interface responsible for model caching is [`IModelCacheKeyFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.imodelcachekeyfactory):

> Creates keys that uniquely identifies the model for a given context. This is used to store and lookup a cached model for a given context.

It has a single method

```cs
object Create(DbContext context)
```

**Update (EF Core 6.0+)** The method has additional parameter

```cs
object Create(DbContext context, bool designTime)
```

The returned object `GetHashCode` / `Equals` methods are used to identify the passed context instance. The default EF Core service implementation returns an object which compares the type of the context.

In order to make the custom context model working, we need to replace it with a custom service which also compares the custom state (`CustomTableName` in our case). The implementation could be like this (using C#7.0 value tuples):

```cs
class CustomModelCacheKeyFactory : IModelCacheKeyFactory
{
    // Pre EFC6.0
    //public object Create(DbContext context) => new CustomModelCacheKey(context);

    // EFC6.0+
    public object Create(DbContext context, bool designTime) => new CustomModelCacheKey(context);
}

class CustomModelCacheKey
{
    (Type ContextType, string CustomTableName) key;
    public CustomModelCacheKey(DbContext context)
    {
        key.ContextType = context.GetType();
        key.CustomTableName = (context as CustomDbContext)?.CustomTableName;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() => key.GetHashCode();
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is CustomModelCacheKey other && key.Equals(other.key);
}
```

The only thing remaining is to replace the existing service with the custom. It can be done inside `OnConfiguring` override:

```cs
optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IModelCacheKeyFactory, CustomModelCacheKeyFactory>();
```

And that's all. Anytime you create context with different `CustomTableName`, EF Core will create a new model and map the `CustomEntity` to that table.

The same technique can be applied to any context containing custom model affecting state by including all custom state in `CustomModelCacheKey.key` tuple. Of course it could be implemented w/o value tuples, just with them the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` overrides are easier to implement. Actually instead of `CustomModelCacheKey` the custom service can return directly value tuple containing the context type and custom state member values.

Comment: Since EF Core 6.0, you will have to implement the `IModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext, bool)` method since `Create(DbContext)` get removed in EF Core 7.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/dynamic-model, https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blame/93dbd42cca6ec27d0aa88188a0ec5319f65db7b0/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/IModelCacheKeyFactory.cs