# Why am I getting the same result from EF core when querying 2 different tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am new to Blazor/ASP.net core/EF and am trying to display some results using Linq. I am coming across the issue of the result coming out duplicated.

I first use context1 to execute the stored procedure GetJobNumbers which takes 2 parameters. A sequence number and an ID number.  The result of this is resulting in 2 rows. The rows each contain a column called table_name.  I use that table_name as a variable in context2 as an argument to call in the correct JobNumber. This is what I have in the Context.cs file for context2:

```
'''
public DBContext(string table_name)
{
JobNumberTableName = table_name;
}

'''
```

This is the logic in the code section that I use to get the information and add it to a list when a button on the form is clicked. The lstImbTable is whats used in the interface code to display the results.

```
'''
public List<Models.TableResults> lstResults;

public void RecordLookupProd()
{
    lstTableResults = new List<Models.TableResults>();
    using (var context1 = new Models.JobTrackingContext())
    {
        var RangeTrackingJobNumber = context1.RangeTracking.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE GetJobNumbers {0}, {1}", SeqNo, ID).AsNoTracking().ToList();

        if (RangeTrackingJobNumber.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var JobNum in RangeTrackingJobNumber)
            {
                using (var context2 = new Models.DBContext(JobNum.table_name))
                {
                    var JobNumberData = (from s in context2.TableResults where s.barcode == barcode select s).AsNoTracking().ToList();
                    lstImbTable.AddRange(JobNumberData);
                };
            }
        }
    };
'''
```

The problem is that JobNumberData is receiving the same results for both iterations even though when I step through the code I can see the correct table name getting used with each context2 iteration.  I have tried with the AsNoTracking() and the result is the same.  I also though with using 'using' the object should of disposed on the next iteration so the data shouldn't of been cached.  Could someone possibly give me some insight on what I may be doing wrong? I have been pulling my hair for the past 4 hours trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I hope I explained this well if not I can try to muster up some screen shots.

Comment: remove surplus tags - this is an ef question

Comment: Most likely the problem is how the `JobNimberTableName` is used (`HasTableName` inside `OnModelCreating`?). See [Entity Framework map model class to table at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51899590/5202563) and [Alternating between multiple models with the same DbContext type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/dynamic-model)

Comment: Sorry about that tags. Thank you for the links. I'll do some more digging.

Comment: Could you share more details?We do not know your dbcontext and also do not know what are your models.You also need to share the procedure.